# Swift: Using a comparative operator in a Switch Statement

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a Switch statement (Swift) that returns a String when a case is greater than a given number. I know this can be done with an "if" or "else if" statement, but I'm looking to accomplish this with a Switch statement. Can this be done or is a Switch statement unable to utilize the "greater than" comparative operator?

```
var score = 101
var letterGrade = ""

switch score{
    case >100:
    letterGrade = "A+ With Extra Credit"
case 90...100:
    letterGrade = "A"
case 80...89:
    letterGrade = "B"
case 70...79:
    letterGrade = "C"
case 60...69:
    letterGrade = "D"
default:
    letterGrade = "Incomplete"
}
```

Comment: You can also write `case 101...Int.max: ...`

Comment: And now you could also write simply `case 101...` with an open range.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is a simple solution, bind it to a constant like this:

```
var score = 101
var letterGrade = ""

switch score{
case let x where x > 100:
    letterGrade = "A+ With Extra Credit"
case 90...100:
    letterGrade = "A"
case 80...89:
    letterGrade = "B"
case 70...79:
    letterGrade = "C"
case 60...69:
    letterGrade = "D"
default:
    letterGrade = "Incomplete"
}
```

That works exactly as you need

Comment: For more consistent code, you could use partial range in first case like `case 101...:`